# Bokeh plot is missing in layout when checkbox group is used

Tags: python, visualization, bokeh, dashboard

Bokeh scatter plot disappears when checkbox is added to layout.

If I exclude ***layout = row([checkbox_group, p])*** and do *show(p)*, I get the intended scatter plot with the color bar.

But when I include ***layout = row([checkbox_group, p])*** and do *show(layout)*, the scatter plot disappears whereas the checkbox and color bar appear.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, ColorBar, HoverTool, CustomJS
from bokeh.models.widgets import CheckboxGroup
from bokeh.transform import linear_cmap
from bokeh.palettes import Iridescent18
from bokeh.models.mappers import LinearColorMapper
from bokeh.layouts import row

gene_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']
file_paths = [r"home/File1.feather", r"home/File2.feather"]
checkbox_group = CheckboxGroup(labels=['File 1', 'File 2'], active = [0])

def checkbox_change(attr, old, new):
    if new:
        selected_file_index = new[0] 
        if selected_file_index >= len(file_paths):
            print("Selected file index is out of range.")
            return
        selected_file_path = file_paths[selected_file_index]
        df = pd.read_feather(selected_file_path, columns=gene_list + ['umap1', 'umap2', 'index'])
        df = df.replace({'index' : 'cell_type'})

        median_score = []
        for idx, r in df.iterrows():
            score = np.sum(r[gene_list])
            median_score.append(score)
        df['score'] = median_score

        source.data = df.to_dict(orient='list')

    checkbox_group.on_change('active', checkbox_change)

# Create the initial plot
df = pd.read_feather(file_paths[0], columns=gene_list + ['umap1', 'umap2', 'index'])

median_score = []
for idx, r in df.iterrows():
    score = np.sum(r[gene_list])
    median_score.append(score)
df['score'] = median_score

source = ColumnDataSource(df)

mapper = linear_cmap(
    field_name='score', palette=Iridescent18, low=df['score'].min(), high=df['score'].max()
)

p = figure(
    title='UMAP Visualization',
    x_axis_label='umap1',
    y_axis_label='umap2',
    sizing_mode='stretch_width',
    height=1500,
    toolbar_location='above'
)
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('Cell Name', '@index')], mode='mouse')
p.add_tools(hover)

p.scatter("umap1", "umap2", color=mapper, source=source)

color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(
    palette=Iridescent18, low=df['score'].min(), high=df['score'].max()
)
color_bar = ColorBar(
    color_mapper=color_mapper, label_standoff=12, location=(0, 0), title='Score'
)
p.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')

layout = row([checkbox_group, p])

show(layout) #show(p)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes from the selected `sizing_mode`s in the `figure` and the `row` function calls.

Your are setting the `sizing_mode` of the figure to `stretch_width` and you are using the default `sizing_mode` of the `row`-layout which is `fixed`. This leads to a behavoir where the figure is shrunk to a minimal width of 0.

To fix this, you can

1. set the `sizing_mode` of the `row` to `stretch_width` or
2. set the figure to a fixed width

#### Minimal Example

```
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(A=[1,2,3], B=[1,2,3], score=[2,4,6]))

p = figure(sizing_mode='stretch_width')
mapper = linear_cmap(
    field_name='score', palette=Iridescent18, low=df['score'].min(), high=df['score'].max()
)
p.scatter("A", "B", color=mapper, source=source)
checkbox_group = CheckboxGroup(labels=['Checkbox 1', 'Checkbox 2'], active = [0])
color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=Iridescent18, low=1, high=3)
color_bar = ColorBar(
    color_mapper=color_mapper, label_standoff=12, location=(0, 0), title='Score'
)
p.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')
layout = row([checkbox_group, p], sizing_mode='stretch_width')
show(layout)
```

#### Output

[image: row with sizing mode stretch width]

#### Comment

The output was created with bokeh 3.1.1. I am not sure if this will work for older versions.